# Add video/Audio url of live streaming in mp media player

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to add url of video/audio to a player on my website.

For Example: I got this code from the "src" of an embed tag

http://www.ndtv.com/common/videos/flash/player/new-wrapper/NDTVVideoPlayer.swf?1384167757

And it did not work.

Please suggest how to get the proper URL,
The media Player is 'MP Plyaer'

Answer (score 0):

Embed your SWF like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Embed SWF</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.ndtv.com/common/videos/flash/player/new-wrapper/NDTVVideoPlayer.swf?1384167757", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>NDTV SWF</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```